# Intersect search results of multiple indexes Lucene efficently

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two Lucene indexes (version 3.5.0), on which I am going to write with Hibernate Search. I need to implement a search that returns a result that is the intersection (AND) of the results on the individual indexes. The main problem is that both the individual results and the final result can be very large, so the combination should be efficient.
Is there an efficient way to do this? Can the [MultiReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiReader.html) help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. MultiReader is the easy way to search across multiple indexes.
2. Marking each Lucene document with its index will likely be the fastest solution; something like `index:global` and `index:local` (if you had `global` and `local` indexes). For example, querying on "exception" could look like:

   (exception AND index:global) OR (exception AND index:local)

where you filter the search results afterwards for the Lucene documents that occur in both indexes.

Note that you cannot perform the naive query:

```
exception AND (index:global AND index:local)
```

as there will be 0 (zero) Lucene documents with both `index:global` and `index:local` values.

Comment: What about `exception AND (index:global OR index:local)`?